# Trouble connecting MySQL to Heroku using Django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, heroku

I have recently switched my Django database from SQLite to MySQL. I have Heroku's free MySQL database installed, called ClearDB and am using this documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb. I can create/install the app and get the url for the database using the following commands:

```
heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite
heroku config | findstr CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
heroku config | set DATABASE_URL= # MySQL database url retrieved from above line
```

After I do this, push everything to Heroku with my database change(which works locally) and open the app, I get the following traceback:

```
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /app/profiles/templates/base.html, error at line 0
   2002
   1 : 
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : {% load staticfiles %}
   4 : 
   5 : {% block styles %}
   6 :     {% endblock %}
   7 : 
   8 : 
   9 : <style type="text/css">
   10 : 


Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in ensure_connection
  216.                 self.connect()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in connect
  194.         self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in get_new_connection
  236.         return Database.connect(**conn_params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py" in Connect
  86.     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in __init__
  204.         super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)

The above exception ((2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/profiles/views.py" in home
  17.     return render(request, template, context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  211.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  168.             len_values = len(values)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  254.         self._fetch_all()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1061.             cursor = self.connection.cursor()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in cursor
  255.         return self._cursor()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in _cursor
  232.         self.ensure_connection()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in ensure_connection
  216.                 self.connect()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in ensure_connection
  216.                 self.connect()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in connect
  194.         self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in get_new_connection
  236.         return Database.connect(**conn_params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py" in Connect
  86.     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in __init__
  204.         super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /
Exception Value: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

I am still learning, and not sure how to troubleshoot this traceback. If you could help me understand what I'm doing wrong, that would be great.

Comment: What is your DATABASES setting? Are you using the value of DATABASE_URL there?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I used the value of DATABASE_URL that the following code provided: `heroku config | findstr CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`. I set the DATABASE_URL using the value I got from there. It didn't seem from the documentation that I needed to configure it anywhere else.

Comment: I didn't ask that. You've *set* the environment variable, but you need to tell Django to use it, no?

Comment: I see. I completely missed that I had to tell Django to use that variable. Thank you. I will try that through the settings.